# tcl threads causing double free or corruption

Tags: c, multithreading, tcl

I'm having issues when trying to run a c function from separate threads, i'm creating two threads for each function that gathers data and returns it to be add it to a blt graph. If I don't use threads and run one by one it works fine, the problem only is cause when i try to put them in threads. I get different errors but double free or corruption is one of them, but all the time backtrace and memory map is displayed.

TCL CODE:

```
proc graphReport {sampleID repstart repstop} {

global xtemp yBio yPart currFrame

#contents has the result for bio and particles for every second

graphCreation

tsv::set graph xtemp_shared 0
tsv::set graph yBio_shared 0
tsv::set details sampleid_shared $sampleID
tsv::set details repstart_shared $repstart
tsv::set details repstop_shared $repstop
#puts "[tsv::get details sampres_shared] [tsv::get details repstart_shared] [tsv::get details repstop_shared]"

thread::create {
    load ./samples.so
    connectDB2
    set temp [getEpoch [tsv::get details sampleid_shared] [tsv::get details repstart_shared] [tsv::get details repstop_shared]]
    tsv::set graph xtemp_shared $temp

}
set xtemp [tsv::get graph xtemp_shared]
#set xtemp [getEpoch $sampleID $repstart $repstop] <-- one by one works fine
set xtemp [split $xtemp ","]
set xtemp [string trimleft $xtemp {\{}]
set xtemp [string trimright $xtemp {\}}]

thread::create {
    load ./samples.so
    connectDB2
    tsv::set graph yBio_shared [getBio [tsv::get details sampleid_shared] [tsv::get details repstart_shared] [tsv::get details repstop_shared]]
}
set yBio [tsv::get graph yBio_shared]
#set yBio [getBio $sampleID $repstart $repstop]  <-- one by one works fine
set yBio [split $yBio ","]
set yBio [string trimleft $yBio {\{}]
set yBio [string trimright  $yBio {\}}]
```

C Code getBio:

```
static int getBio(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[]){
Tcl_Obj *result;
char sampleid[15];
char repStartTime[256];
char repStopTime[256];
int length;
int lengthTwo;
int lengthThree;

if (objc != 4) {
    Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 2, objv, "number of argument error");
    return TCL_ERROR;
}
strcpy(sampleid, Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[1], &lengthThree));
strcpy(repStartTime, Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[2], &length));
strcpy(repStopTime, Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[3], &lengthTwo));

char command[256];
PQclear(res);

strcpy(command, "Select \"bioresults\"('");
strcat(command, sampleid);
strcat(command,"','");
strcat(command, repStartTime);
strcat(command,"','");
strcat(command, repStopTime);
strcat(command, "')");
 printf("%s\n",command);
res = PQexec(conn,command);

result = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp);
Tcl_SetStringObj(result, PQgetvalue(res,0,0), strlen(PQgetvalue(res,0,0)));
return TCL_OK;
```

}

C Code epoch:

```
    static int getEpoch(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[]){
Tcl_Obj *result;
char sampleid[15];
char repStartTime[256];
char repStopTime[256];
int length;
int lengthTwo;
int lengthThree;
char * buffer;

if (objc != 4) {
    Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 2, objv, "number of argument error");
    return TCL_ERROR;
}
strcpy(sampleid, Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[1], &lengthThree));
strcpy(repStartTime, Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[2], &length));
strcpy(repStopTime, Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[3], &lengthTwo));

char command[256];
PQclear(res);

strcpy(command, "Select \"epochtime\"('");
strcat(command, sampleid);
strcat(command,"','");
strcat(command, repStartTime);
strcat(command,"','");
strcat(command, repStopTime);
strcat(command, "')");
printf("%s\n",command);
res = PQexec(conn,command);
result = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp);
Tcl_SetStringObj(result, PQgetvalue(res,0,0), strlen(PQgetvalue(res,0,0)));

return TCL_OK;
```

}

Comment: This looks to be TCL code, not C code, so what is it doing here?

Comment: We'll need the C code for (at least some of\) `samples.so` as well; it sounds like you've got global data without appropriate locking, but that might not be easy to confirm.

Comment: oops sorry guys edited...

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is related to the `res` variable. <looks at what you wrote…> Are you doing queries against a PostgreSQL database here? If so, there might be a much better way…

Comment: yes, I'm doing a query against a postgres database